# Off-by-one error on "X new answers to this question"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

While perusing a question on Stack Overflow, I was presented with the familiar *"X new answer to this question, click to refresh"*. When I did, I was presented with the following:

[image: 1, 2, potato]

This pattern continued with "4 new answers" and "5 new answers", at which point I got bored watching it and came here to report it.

FWIW, the correct number of answers was displayed when I did an F5 on it.

[Post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13974675/1015495)

Comment: I cannot confirm since I cannot see deleted answers, but one of the answers was most likely deleted.

Comment: if you link to the post, someone can confirm, but it is indeed likely a deleted answer.

Comment: You can look up the user and just view their activity. There is an deleted answer on the question.

Comment: @Brandon if I can't see the deleted answer, how can I look up the user's activity?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, I was actually suggesting it to Servy. Sometimes it takes awhile for the OP to provide a link, so I usually just do that instead.

Comment: @Brandon He has no activity on the question in question.

Comment: @Servy, no but there are two other usernames posted in the screenshot. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot more posts now, but there certainly is a single deleted answer to that question from 16 minutes ago. Since you don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts, you couldn't see the third answer.

Comment: So [status-by-design] I guess?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yeah. The good news is, one of the best 10k+ privileges is far fewer seemingly odd quirks :) You'll get there.

Comment: @TinyTim now I just have to earn another....hmm, let's see....carry the two.... OVER 9000 REP to qualify.

Answer (score 3):

There is a deleted answer on the linked question.

Someone posted an answer and then deleted it.  You were sent a notification stating that there was a new answer, but when you went to load it, since it had already been deleted, it wasn't sent to you.